# How do I fix write csv error in R, the match dataframe will not export

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to export my results to csv file. however, I keep getting an error message because of the rows. I tried the try catch to ignore the error but it is not working. I am unable to export the matches dataframe. Any advice would help.

````
library(tidyverse)
library(fedmatch)
library(haven)

setwd("/Volumes/backupdrive/Data")

dfA <- read_dta("ny_reference_state.dta")
dfA <- dfA %>%
  mutate(unique_key_1 = row.names(.))

dfB <- read_dta("ny_final.dta")
dfB <- dfB %>%
  mutate(unique_key_2 = row.names(.))

matches <- merge_plus(
  data1 = dfA,
  data2 = dfB,
  by.x = "name",
  by.y = "business_name",
  match_type = "fuzzy",
  unique_key_1 = "unique_key_1",
  unique_key_2 = "unique_key_2"
)

print(matches)

# Export the matches data frame to a CSV file, ignoring the row count mismatch
tryCatch(
  write.csv(matches, file = "/Volumes/backupdrive/Data/output.csv", row.names = FALSE),
  error = function(e) {
    message("Warning: There is a row count mismatch in the data frame. Exporting the data frame to CSV may result in incomplete data.")
  }
)```
````

Comment: What is the exact message you are receiving? It looks like a warning message and not an error.  Have you checked the output?  Can you share the results from “print(matches)?

Comment: Don't force your own warning message in an error block since as of now *every* error raises that message. Use `ifelse` against `e` to rewrite your message and otherwise raise all other errors.